# Reading File with Strings using overloaded input stream operator>>

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get inputs from a file by overloading the istream operator. For that, I declared it as friend of a class. Then, I take as input that same class like this:

```
file >> *(class pointer);
```

When I'm trying to debug the part of my code that need this to work, it goes as expected into this:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, MYCLASS& n)
{
    string buffer;
    while (!in.eof()) { // input is a file
        in >> buffer;
        // do stuff
    }
    return in;
}
```

The problem is that the buffer stays empty ("") and does not take what it's suppose to be taking from the file. Normally, the format of the file should not be a problem since I'm using a similar method elsewhere in my code without a problem, but here it is in case:

```
* Name Age
* Name Age
* Name Age
...
```

What should I put inside my istream overload function so i get inputs as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This...

```
while (!in.eof()) {
```

...is broken.  You should attempt to read and parse data into your variables, *then* check for failure/eof.  Do not assume that you'll necessarily be at the end of file after reading the last `MYCLASS`.  Instead:

```
string name;
int age;
while (in >> name >> age)
    ...do stuff...
```

If you've really got some kind of leading dot on each line, add a `char` and read into it too:

```
char dot;
string name;
int age;
while (in >> dot && dot == '.' && in >> name >> age)
    ...do stuff...
```

More generally, it's not a very scalable model to assume the rest of the input stream will contain one `MYCLASS` object.  You could instead have a delimiter (e.g. when the first word on a line is not a name, but `<END>`), that terminates the loop.

Comment: Thank you, with what you explained I managed to found a solution!